# Why GestureHandler component blocks focus on <input/>?

Tags: javascript, famous-engine

I have two nodes that I want to drag and I use GestureHandler for that. On nodes I have SignIn and SignUp forms. My GestureHandler blocks focus on my input fields. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This error](https://github.com/Famous/engine/issues/167) should be fixed in version 0.7.0 of the Famous Engine. You may want to try the latest release.